# clean product magento tables that seems corrupted

Tags: magento

I am trying to export a datafeed and it works fine but some products are exported 2 and 3 times.
My magento installation has 2 websites. but we are only using one

However my magento installation in the past had  more websites.

My best guess is that there are some tables with orphaned items, my guess is that when I deleted the websites, it didnt delete the products, because as you can see in the screenshot the titles are different.

I even noticed that the product title its different but the SKU its the same.
Also if I try to search one of those duplicated products in the back end, it wont appear.

What I need to know is how to get rid of those products via mysql?`enter code here`
[image]

**EDIT:**

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[9]]></var>
    <var name="filter/price/from"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
    <var name="filter/price/to"><![CDATA[5000]]></var>
    <var name="filter/status"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
</action>

<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[9]]></var>
    <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
    <var name="map">
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[Unique ID ]]></map>
        <map name="name"><![CDATA[Name ]]></map>
        <map name="condition"><![CDATA[Condition]]></map>
        <map name="description"><![CDATA[Description]]></map>
        <map name="price"><![CDATA[Price]]></map>
        <map name="brand"><![CDATA[Manufacturer]]></map>
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[Manufacturer Part Number]]></map>
        <map name="brand"><![CDATA[Brand]]></map>
        <map name="meta_keyword"><![CDATA[Keywords ]]></map>
        <map name="weight_box1"><![CDATA[Weight ]]></map>
        <map name="special_price"><![CDATA[Sale Price ]]></map>
        <map name="special_from_date"><![CDATA[special_from_date]]></map>
        <map name="special_to_date"><![CDATA[special_to_date]]></map>
        <map name="free_shipping"><![CDATA[free_shipping]]></map>
    <map name="is_in_stock"><![CDATA[is_in_stock]]></map>
        <map name="status"><![CDATA[status]]></map>
    </var>
    <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>

<action method="unparse" type="exportextension/modifier">
    <var name="remove_line_breaks">true</var>
    <var name="remove_html_tags">true</var>
    <var name="add_categories">true</var>
    <var name="category_field_name">category</var>
    <var name="category_delimiter">#</var>
    <var name="first_category_level">2</var>
    <var name="category_path_delimiter"><![CDATA[>]]></var>
    <var name="add_absolute_url_to_field">Url</var>
    <var name="add_image_url_to_field">Image Url</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/export</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[godatafeed.csv]]></var>
</action>
```

Comment: ...how are you exporting the products?

Comment: magento 1.6 I am exportin using dataflow advanced, I am pasting the xml now

Comment: ...and normal dataflow? Does that exhibit the same peculiarities?

Comment: I dont understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is an idea:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

> The Database Repair Tool compares 2 databases (reference [”corrupted”]
>   and target), and updates the target database so it has the same
>   structure as the reference database by doing the following:
>
> - Adds missing tables, or repairs them to have the same engine type and    charset
> - Adds missing fields or repairs them
> - Removes inconsistent data from tables that have broken foreign key    references
> - Adds missing foreign keys and indexes
>
> A typical use case for this tool is to fix the database of an existing
>   Magento installation that has some of the errors mentioned above.

Comment: I need to know manually which tables I should check for invalid data

Comment: The DB tool tells you everything that is wrong - you'd know that if you had given it a go or read the instructions from the link provided.